# Consuming .asmx webservice in C++

Tags: c++, json, web-services, soap, cocos2d-x

How can I consume .asmx webservice in C++. Web-method is returning response in JSON and accepting request via JSON POST. I am developing an application in [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/).
I tried to [follow this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487620/correct-format-for-http-post-using-qnetworkrequest) but its not clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has created a walkthrough for accessing asmx web services from C++: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290758(v=vs.71).aspx

I had a read through the cocos2d documentation, I cannot find any Reference to ASMX services, so wondering why you are using them. ASMX web services were used prior to WCF, which was introduced in 2005.