# Setting request fields in Qt to be sent to server

Tags: node.js, qt, request, sails.js

I have a software which allows user to enter username and password, then submit a request which is sent to my *sailsjs* server where I want to read it using `req.username` and `req.password`.

How do you set the request? Currently I only know how to set header using `QNetworkRequest.setRawHeader("username", username)`, where server side will access using `req.headers.username`, which isn't what I want.

I'm doing this because I already have some codes in my server that reads username using `req.username`, so I need to find a way to set `req` fields. However I want to do it from my client side using Qt. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the username and password in `jsonString`

```
// Build your JSON string as usual
QByteArray jsonString = "{\"method\":\"AuthenticatePlain\",\"loginName\":\"username@domain.com\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}";

// For your "Content-Length" header
QByteArray postDataSize = QByteArray::number(jsonString.size());

// Time for building your request
QUrl serviceURL("https://www.superService.com/api/1.7/ssapi.asmx");
QNetworkRequest request(serviceURL);

// Add the headers specifying their names and their values with the following method : void QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader(const QByteArray & headerName, const QByteArray & headerValue);
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "My app name v0.1");
request.setRawHeader("X-Custom-User-Agent", "My app name v0.1");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", postDataSize);

// Use QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest & request, const QByteArray & data); to send your request. Qt will rearrange everything correctly.
QNetworkReply * reply = m_qnam->post(request, jsonString);
```

[Correct format for HTTP POST using QNetworkRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487620/correct-format-for-http-post-using-qnetworkrequest)

Comment: I did as mentioned but when i did "req.loginName" its undefined.

Comment: I see.. this method puts loginName within req.body.loginName, is there a way to put it under req.loginName instead?

Comment: @Cherple I am taking your server is in sails js. The parameters sent in post requests are available at `req.params('keyUsed')` else if its an `express app`, the data is available at `req.body.keyUsed`. I am not sure if it can be made available at `req.keyUsed`, unless you write specific middleware to do so.