# How do I send payload via a QNetworkAccessManager for post?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm using Qt::QNetworkAccessManager for simulating web post.

[QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post-1)

[image]

This is a request track on a broswer.
How can I send those request payload which are in json format.

Comment: You should form a request with the appropriate header to post. Refer to the `QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this
[Correct format for HTTP POST using QNetworkRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487620/correct-format-for-http-post-using-qnetworkrequest)

```
QByteArray jsonString = "{\"method\":\"AuthenticatePlain\",\"loginName\":\"username@domain.com\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}";

QNetworkReply * reply = m_qnam->post(request, jsonString);
```